# Delete a whole line on keeping the last specific character in unix

Tags: string, unix, sed

I want to delete all lines beginning with a key word CONSTRAINT in a file. But if the end of the line is "))" I want to keep the ") at the end.

For exemple, with input :

```
CONSTRAINT FK_TESTA  ( CD_AAA ))
CONSTRAINT FK_TESTB ( CD_BBB ),
CONSTRAINT FK_TESTD  ( CD_DDD ))
CONSTRAINT FK_TESTC ( CD_CCC ),
```

I want output:

```
)

)
```

I have tried to find the answers without result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know if you have [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) version that supports more than POSIX BREs, this will use POSIX BREs.

Two expressions:

```bash
sed -e 's/^CONSTRAINT.*))$/)/' -e 's/^CONSTRAINT.*//'
```

1. Match on lines starting with `CONSTRAINT` and ends with `))`. Replace the content in those lines with a single `)`.
2. If what's left on the line starts with `CONSTRAINT`, remove all of it.